# How does maven (running under dev profile) include the javascript files inside index.html?

Tags: jhipster

I haven't used jhipster since version 2.0 and I'm currently playing catch-up with version #4.0.6. 
When I try to build the initial app through "./mvnw" (with default **dev** maven profile) from the command line, the application javascript files are not added to the index.html (so that page comes up blank in my browser when I try http://localhost:8080).
Could someone please explain me the normal chain of events which normally lead maven (running with the **dev** profile) to include the application javascript files into index.html ?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.
Best Regards
kbjp

Comment: If it's for angular 2, you must also run webpack,with `yarn start`, see https://jhipster.github.io/development/#working-with-angular. Yarn build is run by maven when using prod profile

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Our workflow is as below, yarn or npm will be used based on choice

1. When you generate an app the files are generated and at the end it triggers `yarn install` task
2. The `postInstall` script in `package.json` is triggered after `yarn install`, this step calls `webpack:build` task
3. Now you should have all files generated and compiled into the `www` folder inside `target` or `build` folder based on build tool selected
4. Now running `mvnw` or `gradlew` will launch the backend and should be available at localhost:8080 this should also serve the frontend compiled from above steps
5. Now if you start making changes nothing will be reflected as its not compiled so you need to either run `webpack:build:dev` manually after changes or have `yarn start` running with live reload

Either you didn't let the postInstall script run or you deleted the target folder

You can also force maven to run webpack task while starting by passing the `webpack` profile like `mvnw -Pdev,webpack`

Comment: Great answer Deepu, could be in doc

Comment: Hi Deepu...you nailed it ! spot on !...after the initial project generation, I did a "mvn clean install". 
This being said, why isn't the frontend-maven-plugin (the "webpack build dev") part of the dev profile ? 
I'm not sure about other developers but usually when I build my project I do a "mvn clean install" (which wipes out the target folder) rather than just "mvn install".

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue, though I am using gradle. [Deepu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42435206/3195526) resolved everything for me too. To force gradle to run the `webpackBuildDev` task (which builds the missing www directory) after a clean, I've added this:

```
processResources {
  doLast {
    if (!new File("$buildDir/www").exists()) webpackBuildDev.exec()
  }
}
```

Presumably this achieves the same thing as the frontend-maven-plugin.

Comment: where did you write this code? can you pls explain more?

Comment: That's in build.gradle at the top level. It updates the `processResources` task (which happens before compilation / packaging) to run the `webpackBuildDev` task if and only if the `www` directory doesn't exist. Essentialy, "if webpack has never been built then build it once".

Answer (score 0):

The single command to build the web assets (images, html, typescript, etc.) is

`yarn webpack:build`

This command will put the web assets where they need to be, i.e. `build/www`

Answer (score 0):

Deppu's answer covers the main conceptual aspect well. I'd like to add my two cents based on running into similar problem specifically with Maven. We know the default preferred JHipster style is to use two terminals, one with ./mvnw and one terminal with yarn start.

However, with our project we sometimes are just focussed on some backend work and run ./mvnw in single terminal and expect the front-end to always be there for use. Though for whatever reasons (eclipse or maven clean steps etc.) the front-end built artefacts may not be present in /target/www always.

So to ensure when we run ./mvnw in single terminal and always have the front-end built, I updated the maven *dev* profile as follows. Basically added the front-end build plugin invoking yarn install (this transitively runs yarn run webpack:build step as part of script already without running dev server) and test . This worked for me.

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and yarn</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                            <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>yarn install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>webpack build test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run webpack:test</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <!-- log configuration -->
        <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
        <!-- default Spring profiles -->
        <spring.profiles.active>dev${profile.no-liquibase}</spring.profiles.active>
    </properties>
</profile>
```