# no gui generated when started jhipster as monolithic application

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

**I am not seeing any frontend interface [blank screen][1] when i start jhipster,** i get just a blank screen when started j-hipster as monolithic application ,i had run " clean build" for Gradle  and it was success,

i tried to run it from command line using " bootRun" as well as started it from within eclipse , i have used gradle for build and chosen angular 2 or 1 (implemented twice), i tried it on chrome and edge/internet explorer.Any pointer on what i may be missing will help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does maven (running under dev profile) include the javascript files inside index.html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432902/how-does-maven-running-under-dev-profile-include-the-javascript-files-inside-i)

Comment: npm install yarn -g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you started webpack, if not try from the console

```
yarn start
```